# Drawing Cards from a Deck

Tags: probability, card-games

You have a standard deck of 52 cards. When drawing 3 cards randomly from this deck, answer the following questions:

What is the probability of drawing at least one Ace card (excluding Jokers)?
What is the probability of drawing 3 cards of the same suit (one of Hearts, Diamonds, Spades, or Clubs)?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please edit your question to show what have you tried and explain where are you stuck.  Please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-bas

Comment: Where is your own working on this question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are 4 Aces in a standard deck, and there are 48 non-Ace cards

The probability of not drawing an Ace in the first draw is (48/52).
The probability of not drawing an Ace in the second draw, after not drawing one in the first, is (47/51).
The probability of not drawing an Ace in the third draw, after not drawing one in the first and second, is (46/50).

Now, multiply these probabilities together:

$p= (48/52) \cdot (47/51) \cdot (46/50)$

This is the probability of not drawing any Aces in all three draws. To find the probability of drawing at least one Ace, subtract this from 1:

$1 - p$

Now, to calculate the probability of drawing 3 cards of the same suit (Hearts, Diamonds, Spades, or Clubs), you can use the following approach:

1. Calculate the probability of drawing 3 cards of the same suit (e.g., Hearts).
2. Multiply this probability by 4 (since there are 4 suits in a standard deck) to account for all possible suits.

So,

$p= 4\cdot (13/52) \cdot (12/51) \cdot (11/50)$

This is because there are 13 cards of each suit in a standard deck, and we’re calculating the probability of drawing one from that suit on each of the three draws.

Comment: thanks you so much!